# Issue with [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1539011] (70007)The timeout specified has expired

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

I need assistance on debugging my apache2 + php8.2-fpm.

based on apache2 error log,

there is a lot of error

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1539011] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xx.xx.xx.xx:58990] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://xx.xx.xx/
```

My current settings for

i am using mpm_worker + apache2 + php8.2-fpm

```
[php8.2-fpm pool settings]

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 133
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 500
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
request_terminate_timeout = 600s

[mpm_worker settings]

[mpm_prefork]
StartServers         5
MinSpareServers      5
MaxSpareServers      10
MaxRequestWorkers    133
MaxConnectionsPerChild 1000

[apache settings]

Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

[php.ini settings]

max_execution_time = 600
```

Appreciate if anyone can help to give an idea where to look for in to find the problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: Everything looks good, no any problem in configuration, you need to consider increasing RAM as it might touched the max children limit on high load and each children can have 128 RAM